# VB.net load controls and content from textfile to textboxes

Tags: vb.net

*...Hopefully this question will be readable...*

I have 27 textboxes.

[image]

The controlname and the text in the textboxes are written to a textfile like this:

```
System.DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd") & "_Names_Config.txt"
            Dim objWriter As New System.IO.StreamWriter(configfile, True)
        'Textboxes
        objwriter.Writeline("tbmax1") 'Control name
        objwriter.Writeline("tbmax1.text) 'The text in the textbox
        objWriter.WriteLine("tbname1") 'Control name
        objWriter.WriteLine(tbname1.Text) 'The text in the textbox
        objWriter.WriteLine("tbext1") 'Control name
        objWriter.WriteLine(tbext1.Text) 'The text in the textbox
'And so on for all the the controls
```

This goes on for all the textboxes and controls, so 54 lines in total.

Works great. The textfile looks like this:

[image]

Alright, now the issue. There will be a `load button` that should *search the textfile -> find the control matching the form's control -> use the line below and fill that spesific line in the control's textbox -> then find next control and do the same.*

## Load  button: This is #1 attempt;

```
'Openfiledialog, then:
            Using reader As New StreamReader(OpenFileDialog1.FileName.ToString)
            Dim currentTextBox As TextBox = Nothing
            While reader.Peek > -1
                Dim line As String = reader.ReadLine()
                If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(line) Then
                    Dim tmpTextbox = Controls.Find(line, True) 'Try to find text according to line 
                    If tmpTextbox.Any() Then 'It´s a textbox name
                        currentTextBox = DirectCast(tmpTextbox(0), TextBox)
                    Else 
                        '?
                    End If
                End If
            End While
        End Using
```

Here comes what I don't understand at all. See before and after picture of what happens to the 27 textboxes after I load the textfile.

**What it SHOULD look like:**

[image]

**What it will look like:**

[image]

"Edit channels" is actually the title of the form itself. I'm speechless. Because I totally don't understand why this happens and the load code, I moved on to another attempt.

## #2 attempt:

```
            Using reader As New StreamReader(OpenFileDialog1.FileName)
            Dim Line As String = reader.ReadLine()
            Dim Current As Integer = 0
            Dim TB As TextBox = Nothing
            While Not IsNothing(Line) 'It will be Nothing when file is over

                '__________________________________________________________________1
                If Line.StartsWith("tbext1") Then
                    'We will increment CurrentChannel, as we changed the section
                    Current += 1
                    For onetonine = 1 To 9
                        tbext1.Text = Line
                    Next
                End If
                If Line.StartsWith("tbname1") Then
                    'We will increment CurrentChannel, as we changed the section
                    Current += 1
                    For onetonine = 1 To 9
                        tbname1.Text = Line
                    Next
                End If
                If Line.StartsWith("tbmax1") Then
                    'We will increment CurrentChannel, as we changed the section
                    Current += 1
                    For onetonine = 1 To 9
                        tbmax1.Text = Line
                    Next
                End If
                '__________________________________________________________________2
'Then I guess this would go on for all the 27 textboxes (probably a really bad attempt)

            End While
        End Using
```

However, this just goes into break mode.

Comment: How about writing each textbox's details into a single line, pipe delimited. Then you always know position 0 is the name, 1 is the value. Then you can avoid the complex if and just use findcontrol to get the value back into the textbox.

Comment: In your first attempt you didn't do anything with currentTextBox after finding it. Just fill up the textbox with the text in next line would do.

Comment: @AndrewMortimer - that is probably a very nice way of doing it. However, I'm not familiar with that way of writing it and not really very skilled, so I'm unsure of how to approach it. I'll try and learn tho! Thanks.

Comment: @jetstream96 Thanks for your answer - you're probably right. Could you explain in a little bit more detail what I'm missing? The #1 attempt is basically a code I've ended ut not understanding too much because of a huge amout of trying and failing + google.

Comment: In general your approach is a good exercise but you should never use it in production code. Control-names are a very bad key for a database record or file entry. They can change in future and you won't notice it. This approach is also not fail-safe because there could be multiple controls with the same name. Also, don't store key-value pairs on different lines, that makes it difficult to put them together afterwards.

Comment: @MadsTheMan In the empty Else block (where you commented with a question mark), add currentTextBox.Text = line. That way you actually fill up the textbox.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Thanks Tim for your great input. I wasnt really aware of this.

Comment: @jetstream96 That actually did the trick, thanks a lot! Guess I wasn't as off as I thought. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first approach works already if you fill the `Else` part:

```
If tmpTextbox.Any() Then
    currentTextBox = DirectCast(tmpTextbox(0), TextBox)
ElseIf currentTextBox IsNot Nothing Then
    currentTextBox.Text = line
End If
```

But you should not use it in production code:

- Control-names are a very bad key for a database record or file entry:

  - They can change in future and you won't notice it
  - They are GUI related and not supposed to be identifiers for properties
  - is not fail-safe because there could be multiple controls with the same name
- don't store key-value pairs on different lines, that makes it difficult, less readable and more error-prone to put them together afterwards

If you want to use one line you need a delimiter that a user never enters, it can be a combination of multiple characters like `|::|` or something similar. Then you can later use `String.Split({"|::|"}, StringSplitOptions.None)` to get both tokens back.

**However**, this is still not a good approach and also not 100% safe. So better  approaches were

- serialize/deserialize a `List(Of String)`.
- If you want to store it in a way that a human can read you should prefer XML.

Here's an example how you can write/read xml easily:

```
' write all TextBoxes to a file '
Dim allTextBoxes = TextBoxPanel.Controls.OfType(Of TextBox)()

Dim doc As New XDocument(New XElement("Channels"))
For Each txt In allTextBoxes
    doc.Root.Add(New XElement(txt.Name, txt.Text.Trim()))
Next
doc.Save(OpenFileDialog1.FileName)

' later read it ... '
Dim xml As XDocument = XDocument.Load(OpenFileDialog1.FileName)
For Each element As XElement In xml.Descendants("Channels").Descendants()
    Dim txt = allTextBoxes.FirstOrDefault(function(t) t.Name = element.Name)
    If txt IsNot nothing
        txt.Text = element.Value 
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Great answer with useful information - thanks a lot Tim.